# Center Span in a table-cell, table-row

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center the text span in the following table-cell, table-row

```
<div style="display: table; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">                
   <div style="display: table-cell; width:400px;">
       <div style="display: table-row; text-align: center;">
           <span>
               Test
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/7p3zgne0/ )

Comment: Are you sure it's `table` -> `table-cell` -> `table-row`? Not `table` -> `table-row` -> `table-cell`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should probably be like this:

```
<div style="display: table; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">                
  <div style="display: table-row; width:400px;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: center;">
      <span>
        Test
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note how the `table-cell` is *inside* the `table-row`. In your code, you have them the other way around.

http://jsfiddle.net/sfcaa3Lk/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, didn't notice that I had those switched around.

Comment: Happy to help! It’s those little typos that keep us awake at night innit?

Answer (score 3):

`table-cell` and `table-row` are inverted.

```html
<div style="display: table; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">                
   <div style="display: table-row; width:400px;">
       <div style="display: table-cell; text-align: center;">
           <span>
               Test
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div align="center">
    center aligned content (like a span)
</div>
```

Apply this to your deepest div node